# Laserline in freespace... and how I can detect the Line for further calculations?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to find a laser beam in different images.

**Example image:**
[image]

**The Original one:**
[image]

I found different approaches, but somehow it doesn't seem to work.
I have now also used a threshold:

```
logicM = image > Threshold
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(logicM, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('image')
plt.title(laserColor + ' band intensity over ' + str(Threshold))
```

to identify the line. Now I want to mark the beam with a dashed line... and then plot the intensity over height (i.e., pixels)... how can this be done? I just can't figure it out.

I found this:
[Vertical curved line detection with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186182/vertical-curved-line-detection-with-opencv)
and that
[Draw a curve line going through the blobs in OpenCV C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406469/draw-a-curve-line-going-through-the-blobs-in-opencv-c/44410748#44410748)

both doesn't work.

EDIT: The theoretical equations can be found here, but is there a easy opencv solution?:
https://mv.in.tum.de/_media/members/steger/publications/1996/icpr-96-steger.pdf

EDIT2:
I tried this, to get the values between the contour.

```
# Sort the contour points by their y-value
contour_points_by_row = {}
for contour in contours:
    print(contour)
    for point in contour:
        x, y = point[0]  # Zugriff auf die x- und y-Koordinaten
        if y in contour_points_by_row:
            contour_points_by_row[y].append(x)
        else:
            contour_points_by_row[y] = [x]
```

But the array is to short. Ony further ideas?

Comment: Please attach the actual example image, not a scaled-down Matplotlib view of it.

Comment: The original image is to large. So I downscaled the image. Hopefully it is now better.

Comment: looks like a static system. you're trying to measure atmospheric attenuation (clouds/fog), aren't you? I'd love to see a full res image and video of that. -- is the camera or the beam ever gonna move? if not, you can work on that assumption and manually define sampling points/lines/rectangles along the beam. -- how about unwarping the image according to a model of the image distortion caused by the lens? -- you might wanna turn the camera sideways so you'll have more resolution along the beam.

Comment: Hi, yes... your right. A want to track a LGS. The idear was to calcualte the backscatter from the laserbeam. Mainproblem is, that i get a view images with distances and angel. I don't know any distortion... currently I'm looking for an way to extract the values between the contour lik AKX discripted. But it seems, that the len of py are to short.

Comment: getting a contour is just *not useful*. you got an answer to your question but your question doesn't solve your problem. -- a simple connected component is enough to denote the red pixels. -- discard all that "curved line" nonsense. that's leading nowhere useful. you need geometry to figure out the ***altitude*** of each image pixel. that requires camera calibration, i.e. intrinsics AND extrinsics. proper intrinsics at the very least (lens distortion), and some messing around for the extrinsics (vanishing point, horizon). you'll need to know how far away the laser beam is from the camera too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick to isolate the beam – there's probably some tool for getting a polyline approximation instead of an area contour too...

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("hQiak.png")

# Mask in HSV space to keep only the vivid red color
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_red = (0, 100, 20)
upper_red = (10, 255, 255)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

plt.imshow(mask, cmap="gray")

# Detect contours from mask
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# Only keep the largest contour
contours = [max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)]

cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
plt.figure(dpi=250)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great... and is there a way to take the values orthogonal to an ideal parabolic line (like in the paper I shared for Intensity studies?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I don't know it outright.